# Why did Doctor Strange want to collect all before pressing the button in "Spider-Man: No Way Home"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, Doctor Strange asked Peter to collect all these other villains from other universes and put them in these cells/locked spaces before he can send them back to their universes, all what is left of the spell is a press of a button.
Peter asked his friends to press the button if they don't hear from him.

The question is, if they could have sent them all back on the press of the button without the need of collecting them, why didn't Doctor Strange just do it there and then?
Why going through the hassle of getting them into those cells?

Comment: Plot.  Makes a great excuse for Spiderm(e)n to go out and get into one last battle with each imported villain.

Comment: So that they don't continue to wreak havoc in this universe? You saw what each of them did as soon as they arrived here

Comment: @Shreedhar I think the idea is that if he presses the button, no matter where they are, they're gone, like Venom.

Comment: For the same reasons you keep an eye on the logs when you release into production; to make sure it went painlessly.

Comment: @Clockwork yes, but also, Strange didn't know how to contain them, at the time. So he asked Peter to capture them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Strange wanted Peter to start capturing the multiversal threats whilst he worked out how to send them back, presumably to minimise the damage they could cause. Strange specifically calls this out to Peter when he tells him to find the threats.

> **Doctor Strange:** Well he sounds jolly. Why don’t you start with him. I need you to capture them, bring them here, while I figure out how to get them back before they destroy the fabric of reality. Or worse, Wong finds out.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: No Way Home*</sub>

Once Strange realises how to reverse the spell it still isn't overly simple; he still has to complete the ritual which is then obviously interrupted by Peter.

> **Doctor Strange:** It’s an ancient relic. *La Macchina di Kadavus*. I’ve trapped your corrupted spell inside, and once I finish the proper ritual, it’ll reverse the spell. And send these guys back to their universes.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: No Way Home*</sub>